# Java SQL update statement is not updating in the table in spite of not getting errors

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
public void updateFields(BorrowedBook borrowedBook) throws SQLException {
    Integer copiesInBorrow = new Integer(0);
    Integer availableCopies = new Integer(0);
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM library_students.book WHERE BookID=" + "'" + getBookID(borrowedBook)+ "'");
        if((rs.next())){
            copiesInBorrow=rs.getInt(11);
            availableCopies=rs.getInt(13);
        }
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE library_students.book SET CopiesInBorrow= ? AND AvailableCopies=? WHERE BookID=?");
        pstmt.setInt(1,++copiesInBorrow);
        pstmt.setInt(2,--availableCopies);
        pstmt.setString(3,getBookID(borrowedBook));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        rs.close();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors and the executeUpdate(); is returning also 1 
what is the problem?

Comment: And please don't select unrelated tags. The C language is totally irrelevant to your problem. I also fail to see the relevance of the `workbench` tag. Therefore I have removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, change to:

```
UPDATE library_students.book SET CopiesInBorrow= ?, AvailableCopies=? WHERE BookID=?
```

Don't use `AND` between the columns you want to update. You could use `AND` in the `WHERE` part to apply the conditions you want.

If you wanted something like this:

```
UPDATE library_students.book SET CopiesInBorrow= ? WHERE AvailableCopies=? AND BookID=?
```

then the use of `AND` would be valid.

From your code I see that you just want to increase the value of a column and decrease another one. You don't need to find first these values in the table and then make the changes.

You can execute this statement:

```
UPDATE library_students.book SET CopiesInBorrow = CopiesInBorrow + 1, AvailableCopies = AvailableCopies - 1 WHERE BookID = ?
```

So change to this:

```
public void updateFields(BorrowedBook borrowedBook) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE library_students.book SET CopiesInBorrow = CopiesInBorrow + 1, AvailableCopies = AvailableCopies - 1 WHERE BookID = ?");
        pstmt.setString(1, getBookID(borrowedBook));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        rs.close();
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```